# SQL Query - Using Information From One Inquiry In Another

Tags: sql

Here is my query. I removed the table names along with other things I am selecting just to make it easier to read.

```
Select 
   b.Key1, 
   b.Key2
From  
   b 

   left join c 
   on c.MailingKey = b.MailingKey 

   left join d
   on d.OrderLineKey = c.OrderLineKey 

   left join e 
   on e.ShipKey = d.ShipKey 

   left join g 
   on d.ShipKey5 = g.ShipKey5 

   left join a 
   on a.DocKey = b.OrderKey

   left join f 
   on f.pMethKey = b.MethKey
```

I need to use Key1 and Key2 that I select in another query to get more information about that key (location, ID, etc.) from another table. I am thinking I will need to make 2 loops within this original query and join them all up. So something like this:

```
Select b.Key1, b.Key2, h.*, i.*
From  b left join 
c on c.MailingKey = b.MailingKey left join 
d on d.OrderLineKey = c.OrderLineKey left join 
e on e.ShipKey = d.ShipKey left join
g on d.ShipKey5 = g.ShipKey5 left join 
a on a.DocKey = b.OrderKey  left join
f on f.pMethKey = b.MethKey left join 
( 
Select* 
From table l 
Where ID = b.Key1
) h left join  ( 
Select* 
From table l 
Where ID = b.Key2
) i
```

I am just not sure how to write equal to b.Key1 and b.Key2.

I am using Microsoft Sql Server Management.

Comment: Sample data w/ expected result would help.  I don't understand the question yet.  Also in plain English, describe what you need to do.  Do you mean you need to use this as a table/view to join to?  could a common table expression work (what database mySQL, sql Server, oracle/)

Comment: Avoid loops, one sql statement to do it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common table expression:

```
with cte as (
Select b.Key1, b.Key2
From  b left join 
c on c.MailingKey = b.MailingKey left join 
d on d.OrderLineKey = c.OrderLineKey left join 
e on e.ShipKey = d.ShipKey left join
g on d.ShipKey5 = g.ShipKey5 left join 
a on a.DocKey = b.OrderKey  left join
f on f.pMethKey = b.MethKey)
Select * from CTE
INNER JOIN othertable o 
 on b.key1=o.key1 
and b.key2=o.key2
```

or do you mean...

Inline view:

```
Select * 
from otherTable
INNER JOIN (
Select b.Key1, b.Key2
From  b left join 
c on c.MailingKey = b.MailingKey left join 
d on d.OrderLineKey = c.OrderLineKey left join 
e on e.ShipKey = d.ShipKey left join
g on d.ShipKey5 = g.ShipKey5 left join 
a on a.DocKey = b.OrderKey  left join
f on f.pMethKey = b.MethKey) CTE 
 on b.key1=o.key1 
and b.key2=o.key2
```

Or do you mean....  something else?

Perhaps:... using an OR statement...

```
Select * 
from otherTable o
INNER JOIN (
Select b.Key1, b.Key2
From  b left join 
c on c.MailingKey = b.MailingKey left join 
d on d.OrderLineKey = c.OrderLineKey left join 
e on e.ShipKey = d.ShipKey left join
g on d.ShipKey5 = g.ShipKey5 left join 
a on a.DocKey = b.OrderKey  left join
f on f.pMethKey = b.MethKey) CTE 
 on o.key1=cte.key1 
 OR o.key2=cte.key2
```

or maybe... an in statement (within this set)

```
Select * 
from otherTable o
INNER JOIN (
Select b.Key1, b.Key2
From  b left join 
c on c.MailingKey = b.MailingKey left join 
d on d.OrderLineKey = c.OrderLineKey left join 
e on e.ShipKey = d.ShipKey left join
g on d.ShipKey5 = g.ShipKey5 left join 
a on a.DocKey = b.OrderKey  left join
f on f.pMethKey = b.MethKey) CTE 
 on o.key1 IN (cte.key1, cte.key2)
```

Comment: This is close but I need to check again the otherTable twice but with a different key each time. I added some code above to clarify what I am trying to do.